# StrGobble doesn't work with \numexpr

Tags: calculations, xstring

I made the following function which strips left, right or both (if present) brackets and it seems to work as intended when used in the document, i.e. `\stripp{1}`, `\strip{(1)}`, `\strip{1)}` and `\strip{(1)}` all output just `1`.

```
\def\stripp#1{%
\IfEndWith{#1}{)}{%
\StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\result]%
\IfBeginWith{\result}{(}{%
\StrGobbleLeft{\result}{1}[\result]%
\result}%
{\result}%
}{%
\IfBeginWith{#1}{(}{%
\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\result]%
\result%
}%
{#1}%
}%
}
```

However, when `\stripp` is used inside `\numexpr` block it throws "Missing number, treated as zero" error. It seems that the problem is caused by behavior of `\StrGobbleLeft' or '\StrGobbleRight` alone, as they also throw same error inside `\numexpr`. What went wrong here and how can it be fixed?
MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\def\stripp#1{%
\IfEndWith{#1}{)}{%
\StrGobbleRight{#1}{1}[\result]%
\IfBeginWith{\result}{(}{%
\StrGobbleLeft{\result}{1}[\result]%
\result}%
{\result}%
}{%
\IfBeginWith{#1}{(}{%
\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\result]%
\result%
}%
{#1}%
}%
}

\begin{document}
\stripp{(1)}%\works as intended

\the\numexpr\stripp{(1)}+1\relax %throws an error

\the\numexpr\StrGobbleLeft{(1}{1}+1\relax %error again

\end{document}
```

Comment: `xstring`'s commands aren't expandable, thus they don't work in `\numexpr`.  You can use the final optional argument like `\StrGobbleLeft{...}{...}[\result]  \the\numexpr\result+1\relax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xstring` commands are not “fully expandable”, so this cannot work in `\numexpr` that expects numbers, not instructions to print them.

You can solve your problem by using a different approach with `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stripp}{m}
 {
  \tomasz_stripp:e { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \tomasz_stripp:n
 {
  % remove a leading (
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { ( } { \str_head:n { #1 } }
   {% there is a leading (
    \tomasz_strip_right:e { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
   }
   {% no leading (
    \tomasz_strip_right:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tomasz_stripp:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \tomasz_strip_right:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { ) } { \str_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
   {% there is a trailing )
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 }
   }
   {% no trailing )
    #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tomasz_strip_right:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

1: \the\numexpr\stripp{1}+1\relax

(1): \the\numexpr\stripp{(1)}+1\relax

1): \the\numexpr\stripp{1)}+1\relax

(1: \the\numexpr\stripp{(1}+1\relax

\newcommand{\test}{1}
\test: \the\numexpr\stripp{\test}+1\relax

\renewcommand{\test}{(1)}
\test: \the\numexpr\stripp{\test}+1\relax

\renewcommand{\test}{1)}
\test: \the\numexpr\stripp{\test}+1\relax

\renewcommand{\test}{(1}
\test: \the\numexpr\stripp{\test}+1\relax

\end{document}
```

As you see, you can also use a macro as the argument to `\stripp`, so long as it eventually expands to a number with possible leading or trailing parentheses.

[image]

How does this work? `\str_if_eq:eeTF` examines the given strings doing full expansion on them. We start by looking at the first item in the (expanded) argument to `\stripp`; if its first token is `(` we strip it off by passing `\tl_trail:n` to the next stage.

The next stage strips off a possible trailing `)` by looking at the last item with `\str_item:nn` and position argument `-1`. If there is `)`, we output the items from the first to the last-but-one with `\tl_range:nnn` and position arguments `1` and `-2`.

If you're using LaTeX prior to the 2020-10-01 release, you need to do also

```
\usepackage{xparse}
```

If you also do `\usepackage{xfp}`, you can replace `\the\numexpr...\relax` with `\inteval{...}` which is more compact.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stripp}{m}
 {
  \tomasz_stripp:e { #1 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \tomasz_stripp:n
 {
  % remove a leading (
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { ( } { \str_head:n { #1 } }
   {% there is a leading (
    \tomasz_strip_right:e { \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
   }
   {% no leading (
    \tomasz_strip_right:n { #1 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tomasz_stripp:n { e }

\cs_new:Nn \tomasz_strip_right:n
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { ) } { \str_item:nn { #1 } { -1 } }
   {% there is a trailing )
    \tl_range:nnn { #1 } { 1 } { -2 }
   }
   {% no trailing )
    #1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tomasz_strip_right:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

1: \inteval{\stripp{1}+1}

(1): \inteval{\stripp{(1)}+1}

1): \inteval{\stripp{1)}+1}

(1: \inteval{\stripp{(1}+1}

\newcommand{\test}{1}
\test: \inteval{\stripp\test+1}

\renewcommand{\test}{(1)}
\test: \inteval{\stripp\test+1}

\renewcommand{\test}{1)}
\test: \inteval{\stripp\test+1}

\renewcommand{\test}{(1}
\test: \inteval{\stripp\test+1}

\end{document}
```